# Angularjs && Google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api

Привет!
Есть такой контроллер, он добавляет маркеры на Google карту

```
angular.module('frontApp')
 .controller('GoogleMapController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.cities = [];

 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 6,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.379433, 31.16558)
 };

 $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
 $scope.markers = [];
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 var createMarker = function (info) {
   $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: $scope.map,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
     title: info.place
   });

   $scope.marker.content = '<div class="info-window">' + info.desc + '<br/>' + info.lat + 'E,' + info.long + ' N, </div>';

   google.maps.event.addListener($scope.marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + $scope.marker.title + '</h2>' +
      marker.content);
     infoWindow.open($scope.map, $scope.marker);
   });

   $scope.markers.push($scope.marker);
 };

 $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, seletedMarker) {
   e.preventDefault();
   google.maps.event.trigger(seletedMarker, 'click');
 };

 $scope.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocompete'));
 $scope.autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', $scope.map);

 google.maps.event.addListener($scope.autocomplete, 'place_changed',
   function () {
     var place = $scope.autocomplete.getPlace().address_components[0].long_name;
     var desc = $scope.autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
     var lat = $scope.autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
     var long = $scope.autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();

     var newCity = {
       place: place,
       desc: desc,
       lat: lat,
       long: long
     };

     $scope.cities.push(newCity);

     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {
       createMarker($scope.cities[i]);
     }

   });
```

});

В моем коде массив `$scope.cities` обновляется только внутри функции `google.maps.event.addListener($scope.autocomplete, 'place_changed'...` А снаружи он пустой.

Отсюда вопрос: "Как добавлять города, введенные через автокомплит, в массив `cities`?"

Comment: ангуляр не знает что произошло событие у карты и поэтому не обновляет view, для указания нужно использовать `$scope.$apply` либо сервис `$timeout`

Comment: @Grundy. Спасибо большое!!!!! Вы мне очень помогли. Теперь работает :)

Comment: Если вы сами решили задачу, можете добавить свое решение в качестве ответа